# Propensity Score Weighting in GAMLSS

Tags: propensity-scores, weighted-sampling, gamlss

in a project of mine i want to use a **propensity score weighted gamlss model**. However, the [gamlss user guide](http://www.gamlss.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/gamlss-manual.pdf) states "*In general using weights that are not frequencies is not recommended unless the user knows what he/she doing and is aware of the problem.*" (p 41). So my first question would be: What exactly is *the problem*? Further, I was thinking of standardizing my propensity score weights such that their sum equals my sample size, to avoid faking a larger sample size than I have. Does anyone have any idea if this makes the SE valid?

I would appreciate every comment/idea on that issue.

Comment: Can you explain what quantity you are trying to estimate and why you are using a GAMLSS model? You can typically use the regression equivalent of a weighted t-test after PS weighting, so GAMLSS seems like massive overkill and will complicate matters.

Comment: Thank you Noah for your comment. I totally agree, that gamlss is quite complicated, but in that case i really want to use one, as i have a proportion outcome with an excess of "one" values. Therefore i use one inflated beta regression, as that naturally fits to the data.

Comment: But if you only want the difference in means, it doesn't matter what the distribution of the outcome is. A weighted linear regression of the outcome on the treatment with robust standard errors will give you correct inference regardless of inflation.